# Why are some of my Gravio processes stuck in a restarting cycle?

Tags: macos, iot, gravio

My Gravio is stuck in a restarting cycle (i.e. the status is turning yellow and green in the menubar menu) on a Mac. I can see it on the settings view where it says "stopped" next to "Trigger Manager" and "Action Manager".

[image: Gravio HubKit status light in menu bar]

[image: Gravio HubKit Mac Settings Screen]

Answer (score 0):

This could be in relation to the fact that you might have Homebrew installed on your Mac. In this case, there are some conflicts happening in the background with image libraries. The following commands linking the system library frameworkss for images to Brew in the terminal should fix the problem:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
mv libjpeg.dylib libjpeg.dylib.backup
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libJPEG.dylib libJPEG.dylib
mv libtiff.dylib libtiff.dylib.backup
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libTIFF.dylib libTIFF.dylib
mv libpng.dylib libpng.dylib.backup
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libPng.dylib libPNG.dylib
mv libGIF.dylib libGIF.dylib.backup
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libGIF.dylib libGIF.dylib
```